# Create Spark dataframe and get records with max timestamp value

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark Dataframe **input_dataframe** as shown below:

```
**cust_id**   **source_id**     **value**     **timestamp_column**
   10              11          test_value       2017-05-19
   10              12          test_value2      2017-05-19
   10              11          updated_value    2017-05-20
```

Primary key for this table is combination of **cust_id** and **source_id**

i have to create **output_dataframe**, which has only the records with latest timestamp(**timestamp_column**) for this combination of primary keys, so my final output is as below:

```
**cust_id**   **source_id**     **value**     **timestamp_column**
   10              12          test_value2      2017-05-19
   10              11          updated_value    2017-05-20
```

Can someome help me achieving it using pyspark code? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use Rank over partition to achieve your outcome

Answer (score 1):

You will need to convert the datatype of the "timestamp_column" before you proceed if you haven't already.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, max as max_timetamp
(cust_tmp.withColumn("timestamp_column", col("timestamp_column").cast("timestamp"))
    .groupBy("cust_id", "source_id")
    .agg(max_timetamp("datetime"))).show()
```

I hope this helps.